# Can a razor form by dynamic so it can be used for both New and Update actions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My razor form looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( "Create", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form"} ))
{

}
```

So this does a POST to my Create action.

I am using the same form for Edit/Updates.  Is it possible to somehow have this POST to the "Create" action for new models, and to the "Update" action for edits?

Comment: Don't use HTML.BeginForm just write it yourself.  Or add a javascript function that switches it.  How do you expect to differentiate between the two actions, if there is no differentiation then just make there only be one method on the controller, createandupdate

Comment: Sure, I would guess that your model has some sort of indicator that shows that it's a create vs an update (an Id for example).  Then you could have `@{ var action = Model.Id.HasValue ? "Edit" : "Create"; }`

Comment: Why not just post to a single `Edit()` method? - assuming you have a `ID` property, then test if its `0` or `null` (i.e. new) in which case, insert, otherwise update.

Comment: The more common pattern is to have a create form and an edit form, but most of the meat is kept in a partial view that they share.  That way you only need to worry about the few things that are different between create and edit and share most of the rest.